# Failure to convert SQL Server varchar to binary in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to accept a user name and return the password and user ID to determine whether or not they have access to a particular Form in a project.

I have searched for a solution and viewed similar questions on this site, but to no avail. Please, help if you can.

The parameter values returned when run in SQL Server debug are:

```
Joseph 
0x6D616368696E653100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
34DFCAA9-1A5F-4AC4-AC43-4A025DD84063
```

My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RMVerifyUser] 
    @UserName AS VARCHAR(40),
    @Password AS BINARY(42) OUTPUT,
    @ClerkID AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT
AS
    SELECT   
        @ClerkID = IDClerk,
        @Password = (CONVERT(binary(8), ClkPassCode, 0))    // ClkPassCode is varchar(50) in the table.
    FROM 
        tblClerkInfo
    WHERE
        ClkName = @UserName
        AND ISNULL(Canceled, 0) = 0

    RETURN
```

And my C# code is:

```
private string retrievePassword(object userName) 
{
    string strPassword = "";
    //uidClerkID = new Guid();

    connect.Open();

    try
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("RMVerifyUser");
        command.Connection = connect;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        SqlParameter retUserName = new SqlParameter("@UserName", userName); // userName is passed in from another method. 
        retUserName.ParameterName = "@UserName";
        retUserName.Value = userName;
        command.Parameters.Add(retUserName); 

        SqlParameter retPassword = new SqlParameter("@Password", strPassword);   // I suspect the error is occurring somewhere in the declaration/definition of this parameter.
        retPassword.ParameterName = "@Password";
        retPassword.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        retPassword.DbType.Equals(DbType.String);   
        retPassword.Size = 50;
        retPassword.Value = strPassword; 
        command.Parameters.Add(retPassword);  // ClkPassCode is nvarchar(50) in the data table.

        SqlParameter retUserID = new SqlParameter("@ClerkId", uidClerkID);  // uidClerkID is a property in a separate class, but I also tried - uidClerkID = new Guid() - in this method. Same error thrown.  
        retUserID.ParameterName = "@ClerkId";
        retUserID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        retUserID.Value = uidClerkID;
        command.Parameters.Add(retUserID);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        uidClerkID = Guid.Parse(retUserID.Value.ToString());

        if (strPassword == DBNull.Value.ToString())
        {
            ReferenceEquals(strPassword, null);             
        }
        else
        {
            strPassword = retPassword.Value.ToString();
            return strPassword;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: You are setting the retPassword DBType to string, and it's a binary...

Comment: Made the recommended change. Now get: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in CSRMSMaster.exe
Additional information: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Byte[]. Maybe I can figure it our from there. Thank you.

Comment: Your logic is wrong too. You never set `strPassword` to a value so the `if` block will always be true. And what is this about `ReferenceEquals(strPassword, null); ` ?

Comment: strPassword is intended to pass the value " " to the stored procedure, hence  the declaration of strPassword = " ";. I will certainly change the ReferenceEquals to string = "" if that is an issue. Thank you for your observations.

Comment: As an aside, if this project is just starting out, think again about storing passwords in the database at all. By all means, store a hash of the salted password and compare against that, but don't store the password.

Comment: Agreed. Downside is that I am trying to convert twelve year old VB code to C# and the tables already exist. This is further complicated by the fact that I am nobody's idea of a good coder. I am truly thankful for all the great help and advice. Was worried that my question would be killed off. So glad it wasn't!

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure has `binary(42)` as the parameter type but in your code you "try" to set it to `DbType.String`. Update your code to use binary. You will also need to use `byte[]` for the local variable. Also note that you should SET the value of `DbType` and in this case I used SqlDbType because it is more specific than just `DbType`. You are doing an equality comparison which has no influence.

```
byte[] password = new byte[42];

try
{
    // begin changed code

    SqlParameter retPassword = new SqlParameter("@Password", password);
    retPassword.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    retPassword.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Binary;
    retPassword.Size = 42;
    command.Parameters.Add(retPassword);

    // end changed code

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();


    // read the value back from the parameter
    password = retPassword.Value != DBNull.Value ? (byte[]) retPassword.Value : null;
```

Comment: Seems that I have many errors in the process. Thank you for the help. I will incorporate your corrections.

Answer (score 0):

I think your password field should be nvarchar instead of binary. Is there an implicit way to convert varchar into binary? I would guess not and I am thinking that you would have to create a special function to get this behavior.

```
declare @binarydata binary
declare @password varchar(50)
set @binarydata = @password
```

Notice the error we get when we try to do this.

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 4 Implicit conversion from data type
>   varchar to binary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this
>   query.

Comment: I found a Microsoft document online that indicates that neither varchar or nvarchar can be implicitly converted to binary. Thank you.